# getting all products from parent category django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

[image]I have products related to child category for example: I have category like that

`Toys`, `Toys -> ChildToys`, `Toys -> ChildToys -> Cars` I have related products to `Toys -> ChildToys -> Cars` and I can get all products by `Cars` but How can I get the products by filtering `Toys` category. What I have done so far

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='category_icons', null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    slug = self.request.query_params.get('slug', None)
    parent_id = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    cats = Category.objects.filter(parent_id=parent_id)

    qs = Product.objects.filter(category_id__in=parent_id)

    print(qs)
    return qs
```

Comment: Can you please share relevant parts of your `Category` and `Product` model?

Comment: just a second please

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you have a look please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to descend the entire tree of children, you'll need to create a method on your `Category` model that fetches all child categories recursively. There's [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281293/recursively-collect-children-in-python-django) that shows you how to do that.

So assuming you have that method `Category.get_family_tree()`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # fields    
    def get_family_tree(self):
        # code from question linked above
        # returns list of `Category` instances
```

then in your view, you can fetch the products like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    slug = self.request.query_params.get('slug')
    categories = Category.objects.get(slug=slug).get_family_tree()
    return Product.objects.filter(category__parent__in=categories)
```

Comment: I have added `get_family_tree` in my `Category` model but `get_family_tree` is not defined. Where exactly should I put this method?

Comment: As a method on your `Category` class. what do you mean by "I have added `get_family_tree` in my `Category` model"? I assume that means you've done `def get_family_tree(self): ...`.

Comment: yes I did the same and I put `children': [self.get_family_tree(child) for child in children]` but I have new error called `TypeError get_family_tree() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: it should be `child.get_family_tree()`. Think about it.

Comment: don't forget to add `self` to the array you return, since you also want the original category to be included, not just the children (and grandchildren, ...)

Comment: sorry I did not understand exactly where I should `self`. Can you share full answer please if possible?

Comment: Please try to think about it yourself. The answer of the link I gave you shows you how to think about recursion, it's not the exact code you want. Just think about it like that: Start with `family = [self]` and then add the family tree for all the children.

Comment: Finally I understood and I got the answer @dirkgroten thank you very much your provided link was very useful by this I found the answer. Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter this with:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.request.query_params.get('slug')
        return Product.objects.filter(category__parent__slug=slug)
```

or for case-*in*sensitive matches:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.request.query_params.get('slug')
        return Product.objects.filter(category__parent__slug__iexact=slug)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Willem but it returns empty value I requested with this url `product/?slug=toys` but it did not work

Comment: @Nerd: but the category is `Toys`, not `toys`.

Comment: @Nerd: use the `__iexact` lookup for case insensitive matching.

Comment: it really returns empty queryset for both cases please help me

Comment: @Nerd: are you sure there are no spacing issues? What if you manually try to retrieve a `Category` with `Category.objects.filter(slug='Toys')`?

Comment: I do not have products in `Toys` but it has its child category i.e `Cars` as shown above from `Toys` I am going to get all products because. `Toys` category has another children and products also are related to other child of `Toys` category and I want to get all products thorough `Toys` category

Comment: @Nerd: exactly but can you retrieve that `Category` (for example in the Django shell). If not, there is something wrong with how you stored the categories in the database.

Comment: @Nerd: then there is no `Category` with that slug. At first slight, it looks like you never "populate" the slug field with data.

Comment: please can you look at that pics i uploaded?